# using # in URL as value key

Tags: java, url, java-server

My java server works as follows:

```
http://locahost:5555/?search="java"
```

The above link would work fine. However, if I ever want to use "#" as part of search string, it all goes wrong. For example:

```
http://locahost:5555/?search="c#"
```

For some reason everything after "#" gets ignored. If I use the decoded version of "#" it works fine again. For example:

```
http://locahost:5555/?search="c%23"
```

The system should be used by people that don't understand url encoding so they would never put %23 instead of #. Is there anyway around it?

Comment: Will that people write the url and its parameters directly in the address bar? If not, how is the url built?

Comment: People not understanding URL encoding shouldn't use the browser address bar to search for things. They should fill an input field in a form, then submit the form. The form will encode URL parameters properly.

Comment: @JBNizet, its just a test server, but at work is getting quite popular and they use it on daily bases. so I was hoping to get it working right.

Comment: The server being a test server doesn't prevent you from providing a form to fill and submit. Where's the problem?

Comment: if at work that kind of searching gets popular they should know about encoding those special characters

Comment: @JBNizet my laziness has no boundaries. :D

Comment: @Kerppag problem is that search can be quite long. sometimes 300 chars or so.

Comment: you could refer to my answer below. it is just a few lines of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the user supposedly should not access the url directly so if they put "c#" in the url there would be no process on the other hand you could use

```
<form action="yourcontroller" method="post">

   <input type="text" name="txtSearch" />

   <input type="submit" value="search"/>

</form>
```

with this, it will take care of the special characters like "#" you mentioned.

don't forget to catch the parameter in your controller

```
request.getParamter("txtSearch");
```

Comment: that's probably the best solution to get it working properly.

Answer (score 5):

Other than encoding it there is no way around it. More over the string after `#`  treats as the `location` of the URL.

String after `#` will not be passed to the server through GET parameters. Use POST method instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Comment: hmm, I see. thanks for the info. it was a long shot anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

It is in the browser. The server never gets a request with the hashtag (#) symbol, just up to the symbol.

A javascript workaround is probably a bad idea.